# When I open a terminal, before any commands, I see "PKG_CONFIG : command not found"

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, bashrc, pkg-config

When I open my terminal window I see this string

> PKG_CONFIG: command not found

Why does it appears? It appears automatically right after I open the terminal window

[image: The error image]

Here is the output of `cat ~/.bashrc` command

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

And here's the output of `cat /etc/bash.bashrc` command

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *|*\ sudo\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.

    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
PKG_CONFIG PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

And this is the output of `cat /etc/profile` command

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots with terminal output. You can copy text from there. Most likely you have something wrong in your `~/.bashrc` file. Please [edit] your question and post the output of `cat ~/.bashrc` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited the question and posted the output

Comment: It looks OK. Maybe you need to look into `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`.

Comment: i edited it and added the needed information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/bash.bashrc` and remove the last line in that file.

Answer (score 2):

The intent of the line at the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which contained a syntax error, was to add a directory to the end of [the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable). When *`VARNAME`* is the name of an environment variable holding text consisting of multiple `:`-separated entries, it is [a common idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom) to write [things like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/11938) *`VARNAME=$VARNAME:otherstuff`*. (Though *`VARNAME="$VARNAME:otherstuff"`* is often better; see below.) In your case, **an erroneous space was added** to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` on the left side of the `=` sign, causing your error.

---

**If you don't need** to set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable, then [Pilot6's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869526/22949) of just removing the line with the syntax error

```
PKG_CONFIG PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

from the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` is the best approach.

**If you do need** to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, though, then you should fix the syntax error by replacing the erroneous space in `PKG_CONFIG PATH` with an `_`  so it reads `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Or you may just want to set that environment variable elsewhere. The systemwide `bashrc` file is not a generally recommended place to set environment variables. See [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) for details.

You may also sometimes see all or part of the right side of an assignment enclosed in double quotes:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

<sup>While [not strictly necessary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23768301/) (in [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)), this may be considered stylistically preferable. In *most* situations, environment variables that might contain spaces should be enclosed in `"` `"` when expanded (`$`). Assignment is an exception where [explicit quotation is not strictly required](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).</sup>

However, I reiterate that this is all only if you actually need to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. If you're not sure how that line got in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, then I don't recommend putting it back. I recommend following the advice in [Pilot6's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869526/22949) except when you actually need to make the malformed environment variable definition work.

---

Finally, if you're wondering **why you got that error message** and how to interpret it, what it means is that the shell attempted to run a command called `PKG_CONFIG`. There is no such command on your system (and shouldn't be). Because the second `_` in `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` was written as a space instead, [the first word](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) of the line was not an assignment (no `=` before the first blank space), so that word was interpreted as the name of the command to be run. So the shell tried to run the `PKG_CONFIG` command with everything else on the line interpreted as a [command-line argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments), and it reported `command not found` for `PKG_CONFIG`.

Comment: Note you should be able to confirm that `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` is already in the default search path by running `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`